# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTDataManager.queryData') - Facebook React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

When I have an error in my javascript (I see the red screen).  I see this message over and over again in my console.

`#CLOWNTOWN (error while displaying error): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTDataManager.queryData')`

I also see the message `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTDataManager.queryData')` if I try to use the `fetch` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the RCTNetwork module in your project.  You can do this by adding the following line to your podfile:

`pod 'React/RCTNetwork'`

Answer (score 0):

This may have happened because you installed a new library which wasn't properly propagated. Navigate to your project directory and run `npm update`